# How to iterate JSON list in Python

Tags: python

I have Json like this :

```
sampleJson = {"tld":".id","pricing":{"register":"225000.00","renewal":"225000.00","transfer":"225000.00"}},{"tld":".co.id","pricing":{"register":"285000.00","renewal":"285000.00","transfer":"285000.00"}},{"tld":".biz.id","pricing":{"register":"40000.00","renewal":"40000.00","transfer":"40000.00"}}
```

I want to result like this :

```
tld : .id
pricing :
register : 225000.00
renewal : 225000.00
transfer : 225000.00
```

please help python code for iterate this

Comment: What have you tried yourself ?

Comment: In your example, `sampleJson` is a tuple and not a list

Comment: Is this an actual JSON string, or a list (or rather in this case a tuple) of dicts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom Ron's answer is of course perfectly good for this case, but requires changing fixed strings should keys in the data change. A more general solution is:

```
def recurse_dict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print(k,':')
            recurse_dict(v)
        else:
            print(k, ':', v)

for d in sampleJson:
    recurse_dict(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
sampleJson = [{"tld":".id","pricing":{"register":"225000.00","renewal":"225000.00","transfer":"225000.00"}},{"tld":".co.id","pricing":{"register":"285000.00","renewal":"285000.00","transfer":"285000.00"}},{"tld":".biz.id","pricing":{"register":"40000.00","renewal":"40000.00","transfer":"40000.00"}}]

for item in sampleJson:
    print(f'tld: {item["tld"]}')
    print('pricing :')
    for key, value in item["pricing"].items():
        print(f'{key} : {value}')
```

Output -

```
tld: .id
pricing :
register : 225000.00
renewal : 225000.00
transfer : 225000.00
tld: .co.id
pricing :
register : 285000.00
renewal : 285000.00
transfer : 285000.00
tld: .biz.id
pricing :
register : 40000.00
renewal : 40000.00
transfer : 40000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that recursively prints a dictionary, something along these lines:

```
sampleJson = {"tld":".id","pricing":{"register":"225000.00","renewal":"225000.00","transfer":"225000.00"}},{"tld":".co.id","pricing":{"register":"285000.00","renewal":"285000.00","transfer":"285000.00"}},{"tld":".biz.id","pricing":{"register":"40000.00","renewal":"40000.00","transfer":"40000.00"}}

def recursive_dict_print(d):
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], dict):
            print(k, ": ")
            recursive_dict_print(d[k])
        else:
            print(k, ":", d[k])

for d in sampleJson:
    print("next dict")
    recursive_dict_print(d)
```